# What's a good database for full text search on a large number of relatively small text documents? (C# backend)

Tags: c#, database-design, full-text-search, sentiment-analysis, keyword-search

I am designing a system that aims to ingest large numbers of documents.  I want to support full text search on the document contents, as well as other metadata (keyword/sentiment analysis).  How keyword/sentiment analysis is done is beyond the scope of this question.  But it is worth considering that this sort of metadata needs to live along side the search-able documents.

**The main assumptions are:**

- by large I mean initially a few 100,000 with the goal of reaching millions
- the documents are 0-15kb.
- these documents are text (utf-8)
- desire to be able to full-text-search document contents
- hosted on a single machine, no cloud/distributed services
- new documents are inserted continuously (roughly 1-2 per second)
- ad hoc text searches
- more complicated query use cases would be:

  - show me all documents that are about 'Widgets' that are positive from this daterange

C# is the language of choice for fetching documents, processing, storing and retrieving from db.  So having C# bindings is a big plus.  Or at least an easy way to bridge the gap.

### Naive Approach

A naive approach is to use MySQL along with Apache's Lucene.  Having the document contents stored as files with references to them in the DB, or having the document contents as a Text field in the databse.

Then I could use one of the C# wrappers to Lucene like [Lucene.Net](https://github.com/apache/lucene.net)

My concern/question with this approach is whether or not the size of my data and what I want to do with it is too much for MySQL.  I know it is silly to do premature optimization, and that oftentimes people think they need some 'big data' solution when it turns out that a regular SQL database does just fine.  My other main concern with this approach is that it would be too 'clunky' and cumbersome to develop compared to some potential alternatives.

### Alternatives

From doing some research, one alternative that looks promising is using CouchDB with Lucene.  I have come across two libraries that solve this:

- [couchdb-lucene](https://github.com/rnewson/couchdb-lucene)
- [Divan](https://github.com/foretagsplatsen/Divan)

### What I'm looking for:

I haven't done a whole lot with this size of data.  I wonder:

- Does this amount of data and use case merit a non-relational database?
- Should documents live in the database, or as files with references in the database?
- Is there a database/full-text-search technology that is particularly suited for this scenario that I haven't considered?

Comment: Maybe you can repost this on [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) or have the post moved there. It is a good and valid question to ask, in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you look into RavenDb.  It uses Lucene and is 100% .Net.  It has text analyzers for doing full text indexing and fuzzy searches.